# jQuery Append: Generic way to move options to bottom of select lists

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with several dozen pages. Across all pages, I need to use jQuery to move specific options in select lists to the bottom of the list.

When I have a single select on the page, this works just fine:

```
$('select').find('option[value="optionZ"]').appendTo('select');
```

The issue is when I have more than one select, the optionZ value appends to each list multiple times.

```
        <select name="select1">
            <option value="optionA">option A</option>
            <option value="optionZ">option Z</option>
            <option value="optionB">option B</option>
            <option value="optionC">option C</option>
        </select>

        <select name="select2">
            <option value="optionA">option D</option>
            <option value="optionZ">option Z</option>
            <option value="optionB">option E</option>
            <option value="optionC">option F</option>
        </select>
```

The only way I have been able to solve this is by targeting by name:

```
$('select[name=select1]').find('option[value="optionZ"]').appendTo('select[name=select1]');     

$('select[name=select2]').find('option[value="optionZ"]').appendTo('select[name=select2]');
```

I am looking for a generic way of doing this without referencing the name of the element everytime for maintainability purposes. Essentially "If option Z exists in this select list, append it to this select list". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine your `select` and `option` selectors, and append to the parent:

```js
$('select option[value = "optionZ"]').each(function () {
  var $opt = $(this);
  $opt.appendTo($opt.parent());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <select name="select1">
            <option value="optionA">option A</option>
            <option value="optionZ">option Z</option>
            <option value="optionB">option B</option>
            <option value="optionC">option C</option>
        </select>

        <select name="select2">
            <option value="optionA">option D</option>
            <option value="optionZ">option Z</option>
            <option value="optionB">option E</option>
            <option value="optionC">option F</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but you can move just the selected option to the bottom of the list by putting a button and the `<select>` element in a containing div.

You can then use .siblings() and .children() functions to find the selected option and append it to the end.

```
<div id="select1">
  <select name="select1">
    <option value="optionA">option A</option>
    <option value="optionZ">option Z</option>
    <option value="optionB">option B</option>
    <option value="optionC">option C</option>
  </select>
  <button>
  Move to Bottom
  </button>
</div>

$( "button" ).click(function() {
    var thisSelect = $( this ).siblings("select"); 
  var selected = thisSelect.children(":selected");
  thisSelect.append(selected);
});
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/8fhtu5sa/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `this` keyword to reference to currently used select. Assuming that you'd use a `change` event handler, it would look something like this:

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    $(this).find("option:selected").appendTo( this );
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3tphmqvv/